# unused arguments and invalid subscript type list error in R

Tags: r, statistics

i am struggling with an assignment and i would like your input.
*note: this is a homework but when i tried to add the tag it said not to add it..*
i don't want the resulting code, just suggestions on how to get this working :)

so, i have a t.test function as such:

```
    my.t.test <- function(x,s1,s2){
        x1 <- x[s1]
        x2 <- x[s2]
        x1 <- as.numeric(x1)
        x2 <- as.numeric(x2)
        t.out <- t.test(x1,x2,alternative="two.sided",var.equal=T)
out <- as.numeric(t.out$p.value)
        return(out)
    }
```

a matrix 30cols x 12k rows called `data` and an annotation file containing col names and data on the colums named `dataAnn`

`dataAnn` first column contains a list of M (male) or F (female) corresponding to the samples (or cols) in `data` (that follow the same order as in `dataAnn`), i have to run a t.test comparing the two samples and get the p values out

when i call

```
raw.pValue <- apply(data,1,my.t.test,s1=dataAnn[,1]=="M",s2=dataAnn[,1]=="F")
```

i get the error

```
Error in t.test(x1, x2, alternative = "two.sided", var.equal = T) : 
  unused argument(s) (alternative = "two.sided", var.equal = T)
```

i even tried to use

```
raw.pValue <- apply(data,1,my.t.test,s1=unlist(data[,1:18]),s2=unlist(data[,19:30]))
```

to divide the cols i want to compare but in this case i get the error

```
Error in x[s1] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

i have been looking online, i understand that the second error is caused by an indices being a list...but this didn't really clarify it for me...
any input would be appreciated!!

Comment: You have overwritten the `t.test` function. Try calling it something like `my.t.test`, or when you want to call the original one use `stats::t.test`

Comment: @James is exactly right.

Comment: @James and @ David i actually just edited the code to change the `t.test` to `my.t.test` avoiding recursions but i get the same error about `unused arguments`

Comment: @Seb: That's because you still have the overwritten `t.test` rattling around in your environment. Do `rm(t.test)` (which will remove your defined `t.test` but leave the built-in one) then run it again.

Comment: @David -- it worked! i didn't realized that i was calling the old t.test function i created from inside my new my.t.test :-/!! thanks!!!

Comment: Yep- that's a common danger. @James should post his comment as an answer so you can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overwritten the `t.test` function. Try calling it something like `my.t.test`, or when you want to call the original one use `stats::t.test` (this calls the one from the `stats` namespace). Remember that when you have overwritten a function you need to `rm` it from your workspace before you can use the original one without specifying the namespace.